# What is the right way to reset data in redux store after post request?

Tags: reactjs, redux, single-page-application

Often when I use Redux and server api I have a problem - In the store keep irrelevant data.

Abstract example:
We have a comment form with a field for display errors. When a user sends a comment, we send a POST request to the server and the server may return different responses - 200, 401, 403, 422, 500.
For example, our server return code is 422. We call a specific Failure Action and we save the error in the store. A React component receives the props with an error from the store and it renders the error on a page. Next, the user opens other pages (we talk about SPA) and after some time, they return to the page with the comment form, where again you see the error, because our component receives an error props again from the store, but this error refers to a previous request and it shouldn't be displayed.

I have considered some solutions, but I’m not sure about them:

1. When the component unmounts we can reset the request state. For all requests we should create Action and Reducer which will reset the state. We should dispatch the reset action manually for each request in all components. Maybe it’s not such a good idea.
2. We can add a unique identifier or a timestamp for each Failure or Success Action and in the component do checks. For example, if we will use timestamps we can check the current time plus a value and request time. But what value to choose? One second, five seconds, maybe more or less? I don't know, and probably it’s not a good decision too.
3. Maybe, do we have a way not to keep errors in the Redux store? Honestly, I’m not sure.
4. We can create a component for display errors and reset by timeout. I think it’s maybe better than the other solutions.

How do you solve this problem in your apps? Thanks for any help and ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your API calls are withing action creators, you will want your API errors in your store. Otherwise, you'd never get the error response from the API.

I would take advantage of `@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE` action. If your router is connected, every time your route changes, it will dispatch that action.

I'd listen to that action to clear the error in your store. Perhaps, I'd have a reducer to just handle requests status.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your request errors to be global, it sounds like they shouldn't be in your Redux store. It's okay to keep them in React state in that case. https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#do-i-have-to-put-all-my-state-into-redux-should-i-ever-use-reacts-setstate